# similarity between the two files using grep, why this work: grep -i "-ffile1" file2

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two files, file1 and file2, and want to find the similarity between the two files using grep.

why -f should flow by the file name without spaces when I surround the -f file1 with quotes?

this will work

```
grep -i "-ffile1" file2
```

but this will not work

```
grep -i "-f file1" file2
```

but if I remove the quotes these two cases will work

```
grep -i -ffile1 file2
grep -i -f file1 file2
```

Comment: What is purpose of quoting `"-ffile1"` or `"-f file1"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, one-letter options with arguments can be either presented as two arguments, i.e. either

(1)

- Nth parameter to grep : `-f`
- (N+1)st parameter to grep : the filename.

or

(2)

as a single parameter, where the name **immedately follows** the option letter: `-ffilename`

In your second attempt, `"-f xxxx"`, you are passing a single parameter (which corresponds to case (2)), but what follows immediately after the option letter, is a space. Hence you specify a file name starting with a space. Such a file does not exist. Therefore, you see a different behaviour in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The `-f` option can be used in two ways: either by specifying the file name in the next argument, or by specifying the file name in the same argument right after `-f`.

When you quote the argument like `"-f file1"`, the second case kicks in and `grep` looks for a file called `" file1"`, with a leading space.  Since your file is called `"file1"`, without a leading space, `grep` fails to find it.

If the file *did* have a leading space in its name, it would work:

```
$ echo findthis > " file1"
$ echo findthis > file2
$ grep -nH "-f file1" file2
file2:1:findthis
```